# Allowing users to use either email or username for login using Passport, LocalStrategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am relatively new to web development, and I am creating a website with NodeJs and Express that would ask for a username and email when registering. Currently, it only accepts username for login. I am using Passport and LocalStrategy. I want users to be able to provide either the username or email in the same input field, How can I do that? I have searched the internet and found similar questions, but I haven't been able to implement their answers successfully. Here are the relevant parts of my app.js

```
var express    = require("express"),
    mongoose   = require("mongoose"),
    passport = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
    User = require("./models/user");

// PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "Once again Rusty wins cutest dog!",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// Register
app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
    res.render("register");
});
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var newUser = new User({email: req.body.email, username: req.body.username});
    console.log(newUser);
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.render("register");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
           res.redirect("/");
        });
    });
});

// Login
app.get("/login" , function(req, res) {
    res.render("login");
});
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
        successRedirect: "/campgrounds",
        failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), function(req, res) {
});
```

This is my user model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was diving deeper into the docs of Passport Local Mongoose and found a way to do this. I'll leave the answer here in case someone finds it useful. When doing the plugin to the user model one can specify options:

```
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, options);
```

With the option usernameQueryFields one can provide other fields to look for the username (eg. email). So I changed my user.js like this:

```
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameQueryFields: ["email"]});
```

And now it users can provide either email or username in the login form